# Does holding down Ctrl/Shift while clicking refresh actually have an effect in modern browsers?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, safari, opera

I have been pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking refresh for so long out of habit that I am not even sure it has any effect in modern browsers.

In the past it was used to do a 'hard refresh' - i.e. not reloading anything from the cache.

Does this still apply? If so, is the effect it has still the same?

Comment: You haven't been using CTRL?

Comment: hmm.. depends which version of which browser no? Updated my question anyway

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It does still work and helps bypass the cache - here's a break down of the shortcuts for the common browsers:

**Internet Explorer**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click refresh button

**Google Chrome**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click refresh button

**Safari**

- Version 4 or newer: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click refresh button
- Version 3 or older: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

**Firefox**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click refresh button

**Opera**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: There's no `Shift + R` shortcut in the Opera, at least in the latest versions and I doubt about `Shift + click refresh` button either.

Comment: Thanks @Malcolm - I'm not an Opera user so I couldn't confirm for sure. Please feel free to edit my answer if you know what the shortcut is on Opera.

Comment: @Malcolm: Both `Ctrl + F5` and `Shift + F5` work for Opera since version 11.62 (see [changelog, under Network](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/windows/1162/) for details).

Comment: @aaamos I left that comment long before the release of the version you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Under Firefox 4, a normal refresh will generally reload basic content such as HTML as well as CSS and JavaScript.  If you force a full refresh, the browser will reload all content, including images and all other objects, from the server.