# Is there a way to make web browsers completely reload a webpage?

Tags: browser, web-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force Internet Explorer (IE) to REALLY reload the page?](https://superuser.com/questions/81182/how-to-force-internet-explorer-ie-to-really-reload-the-page)
>   [Does holding down Ctrl/Shift while clicking refresh actually have an effect in modern browsers?](https://superuser.com/questions/278553/does-holding-down-ctrl-shift-while-clicking-refresh-actually-have-an-effect-in-m)

I don't like IE in general however when you hold control and click the reload button it completely reloads the webpage. Pulls it from the source if you will. Is there a way to do this with Firefox and Chrome... extensions, addons, whatever...

Comment: Not a dup, that guy wanted to do it in IE and I want to do it in all the other browsers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate

It has a pretty detailed description of what a refresh vs a shift-refresh does.

Firefox and Chrome should be pretty much the same as IE in this regard.

From the above link:

> Generally speaking:
>
> F5 may give you the same page even if the content is changed, because it may load the page from cache. But Ctrl-F5 forces a cache refresh, and will guarantee that if the content is changed, you will get the new content.

Comment: @bfhd would you mind summarize what that SO answer says, that way users don't have to follow the link in order to get an 'answer'

Comment: okay, all done!